# Changes not saved to database when updating the M expression for an SSAS tabular model with .NET

Tags: c#, azure, ssas-tabular

Scenario:
we have a table with partition and we have to update the partition query using .NET

We use the code below to replace the existing M Expression with a new one, but the changes are not updating at the database level (Analysis Tabular).
Are there any syntax errors or problems in this code?

```
TOA.Partition partition = m.Tables.Find(Table).Partitions[1];

OverrideCollection oc = new OverrideCollection
{
  Partitions =
  {
    new PartitionOverride
    {
      OriginalObject =partition,
      Source = new MPartitionSourceOverride
      {
        Expression=expressions
      }

    }

  }

};


var listOc = new List<OverrideCollection>();
listOc.Add(oc);
partition.RequestRefresh(TOA.RefreshType.Add, listOc);
// m.Tables[Table].Partitions[1].Refresh(TOA.RefreshType.Full, listOc); //it is not working 
db.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
db.Model.SaveChanges();
m.SaveChanges();
TOA.Partition partition1 = m.Tables.Find(Table).Partitions[1];
```

Comment: Could you properly indent your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I've editted your question to try to make it clearer and easier to answer.  Please edit it again if you need to add more details.  In particular, can you describe what happens when you run this code, especially if there are any error messages or warnings.  Also take a look at [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help section.